# Value of variable with "var" keyword changes after using the same variable in For loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain that why the value of `i` with the `var` keyword changes after re-declaring the same variable in a `for` loop?

For example the value `10` is set to variable `i` and after setting the condition in for loop `i < 40` the value changes to i?

```js
var i = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  // code block
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: A `var` variable is scoped to the enclosing function (or global scope). The second `var` declaration has no effect; there's only one `i` variable.

Comment: I've not encountered this, but I would assume it's due to the way JS [hoists variable definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), such that the two in your example are being combined, or the second is being ignored.

Answer (score 4):

`var` statements are scoped to the **function** they are declared within and the `for` loop is in the same function as the line immediately before it. (For historical reasons, redeclaring a variable with `var` doesn't throw an error, it is just silently ignored (although the assignment isn't).)

Use a `let` statement if you want a variable scoped to the **block**.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first part of your loop, you are re-declaring the same var.

To solve this, you must change the name of the first "i" var. For example "j"

And on the first part of your loop, equal "i" to "j" -> var i = j

Here is the snippet

```js
var j = 10;
for (var i = j; i < 40; i++) {
  // code block
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: "Beacouse in the first part of your loop, you are re-declaring the same var." — The question already observes that. It is asking why.